# How to select multiple Z field from attribute table to perform IDW interpolation using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy

I have 12 point feature datasets for different month. I want to perform IDW interpolation.

I have created the python code but  its taking only one "Z" field for different month feature datasets from the attribute. Below I have mentioned the code. How to assign here multiple Z field from each month folder (JANUARY, FEBRUARY......DECEMBER).

Point feature class from different month folder (e.g. For January Merged_001, for FEBRUARY Merged_002.......for DECEMBER Merged_012 ) and want to perform IDW interpolation and save it as on same month folder as it Z field name (Max_Temper, Min_Temper, Precipitatat, Wind, Relative_H, Solar) with month  (e.g for January 001_Max_Temper, 001_Min_Temper, 001_Precipitatat, 001_Wind, 001_Relative_H, 001_Solar).

After  Whatever Solar raster for different month  (for January 001_Solar....for DECEMBER 012_Solar) we will get, I want to do some calculation (001_Solar * 30) *0.5 and save it 001_sr ........012_sr in Month wise folder.

Here is my code.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.parallelProcessingFactor = "100%"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

env.workspace = "D:\SWAT-WEATHER-DATA2\APRIL"

# Set local variables
inPointFeatures = "D:\SWAT-WEATHER-DATA2\APRIL\Merged_004.shp"

zField = "Min_Temper" #Z_Filed Name= Max_Temper, Min_Temper, Precipitatat, Wind, Relative_H, Solar

cellSize = 0.002298707671
power = 2
searchRadius = RadiusVariable(10, 150000)

#Mask region of interest
mask="D:\Gujarta Shape file\GUJARATSTATE.shp"

# Execute IDW
outIDW = Idw(inPointFeatures, zField, cellSize, power, searchRadius)

# Execute Mask
IDWMASk = ExtractByMask(outIDW, mask)

# Save output, except Solar Radiation raster
IDWMASk.save("004_Min_Temp.tif")

# 004_Max_Temp.tif, 004_Min_Temp.tif....Solar

#Only for Solar Radiation raster
#PAR = (IDWMASk * 30) * 0.5

#Save output, Only for Solar Radiation raster
#PAR.save("003_sr.tif")

#print done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a list of your Z Fields and loop through them

```
zFields = ["Min_Temper", "Max_Temper", "Min_Temper", "Precipitatat", "Wind", "Relative_H", "Solar"]

cellSize = 0.002298707671
power = 2
searchRadius = RadiusVariable(10, 150000)
#Mask region of interest
mask="D:\Gujarta Shape file\GUJARATSTATE.shp"

# Execute IDW
for zField in zFields:
    outIDW = Idw(inPointFeatures, zField, cellSize, power, searchRadius)
    # Execute Mask
    IDWMASk = ExtractByMask(outIDW, mask)

    if not zField == "Solar":
        # Save output, except Solar Radiation raster
        IDWMASk.save("004_{}.tif".format(zField))
    else:
        #Only for Solar Radiation raster
        PAR = (IDWMASk * 30) * 0.5
        #Save output, Only for Solar Radiation raster
        PAR.save("004_{}.tif".format(zField))
```

The line `IDWMASK.save("004_{}.tif".format(zField))` will save each output file with the name of the relevant field, e.g. `004_Min_Temper.tif`